# Call to a member function query() on a non-object in pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I require the pdo_connect in the index before requiring anything else
Using the foreach(see below) in the index.php works but when I use it in the function 'test' (which is a seperate file) I get the error:

Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Already tried requireing the pdo_connect in the seperate file as well which gives the same error

I'm completely new to PDO and a beginner coder and would really appreciate it if someone can help me out!

pdo_connect.php:

```
        $host= 'localhost';
        $dbname= 'secret';
        $user= 'secret';
        $pass= 'secret';
        $input = 'secret';

        try 
        {  
          $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);  
          $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        }  
        catch(PDOException $e) 
        {
            file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);  
        }
```

Function (testfile.php):

```
function test($UserName,$PassWord)
{

    foreach($DBH->query('SELECT * FROM users') as $row) 
    {
        echo $row['username'].' '.$row['password']; //etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: Read about [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) in PHP. `$DBH` is not accessible inside `test()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass your $DBH as param to **test** function, $DBH is not visible inside your **test** function.

Try:

```
function test($DBH,$UserName,$PassWord)
{

    foreach($DBH->query('SELECT * FROM users') as $row) 
    {
        echo $row['username'].' '.$row['password']; //etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked great! I've been stupid but hey! You learn from that right? I'll remember this the rest of my life probably, Thanks for helping out mate!